# How to get dynamically changed font height?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios8, ios9

I am trying to change the custom tableviewcell height based on system font height.
But i didn't find any api to get system font height.

Note: I can't calculate font height using any cell label as "HeightForRowAtIndexPath" will call before configuring the cell.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: try to use constraints and add two lines of code self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 ;
self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: Thanks @KishoreKumar , But I got the solution , and i wanted to check font height ,here is the solution:

UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody].lineHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fellas,
Got the solution.

```
[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody].lineHeight;
```